# Lorentz transformation of electromagnetic 4-potential

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

I'm looking for the exact correspondence between
Lorentz transfer four vector

[image: Lorentz transfer four vector]

and the four vector of scalar and vector potential $A^\mu = (\phi(t,\vec{x}),\vec{A}(t,\vec{x}))^{T}$.

Does $ct=A(t), x=\phi(t),y=\phi(x), z=\phi(x)$?

Comment: Your question as it stands does not appear to make much sense. Are you trying to say that the components of the 4-potential somehow correspond to the components of the 4-position vector?

Comment: Sorry about the incomplete post . Yes , I'm asking about the correspondence of the components .

Comment: Is my hypothesis right ...?

Comment: No, it is definitely not. The only 'correspondence' is that both have four components, but that's just what the answer posted below showed.

Comment: I saw here right now .

Comment: Ok now I understood your "correspond" meant only the part of "four components" .

Answer (score 6):

Covariant notation is a simple way to say how something transforms under Lorentz. An object with an index, e.g. $z^\mu=(z^0,\vec z$), transforms under Lorentz as,
$$
{z^{\prime}}^{\nu} = {\Lambda^\nu}_\mu z^\mu
$$
where $\Lambda^\mu_\nu$ is the matrix you have written down in your question. $z^\mu$ is called a four-vector. This transformation property is true regardless of whther $z^\mu$ represents position $z^\mu=x^\mu=(ct,\vec x)$, momentum $z^\mu=p^\mu=(E/c,\vec p)$, the four-vector potential $z^\mu=A^\mu=(\phi/c,\vec A)$, or anything else that is a four-vector.

The correct identification for similar components of a four-vector between position and four potential would be,
$$ 
ct \leftrightarrow \phi/c\\
x \leftrightarrow A_x\\
y \leftrightarrow A_y\\
z \leftrightarrow A_z\\
$$
i.e. $ct \leftrightarrow \phi/c$ and $\vec x \leftrightarrow \vec A$.

I advise you read a few chapters on covariant notation in special relativity. You should be able to figure out how $A^\mu$ transforms because you know how $x^\mu$ transforms and you know that all four-vectors transform in the same way.

Comment: Thank you for your quite concrete answer! I could understand a lot and I will also check the special relativity as you mentioned .

Comment: (I'm non native english speaker though...) I interpreted that the vector potential is related only to the position vectors of four vectors and scalar potential is related only to the time . Is this right ?

Comment: Do you think that the Matrix part of Lorentz transform also correspond to the scalar potential ?

Comment: I still don't get why the time correspond variable only related to one factor of Lorentz.  My guess was the factor of x of Lorentz will be related to the A（t）or Φ（t） . But it seems Φ（t）is related to the ct of lorentz so where does the A(t) has gone from the electric magnetic four potential ? Sorry for the multiple questions or even before I'm checking up the special relativity .

Comment: @user44629 I think what you're getting at is incorrect. EACH component of $A^\mu$ can be dependent on all four spacetime components.

Comment: Do you mean by there are no exact correspond ?

Comment: @user44629 No. Each component can depend on ALL spacetime coordinates.

Comment: @innisfree Could you update your answer to expand a little bit on that (a few sentences should suffice)?

Comment: you mean interacting ?

Comment: ok , sorry for taking your time .

Comment: My interpretation now is every electromagnetic four potential can be ct,x,y,z .

Comment: His answer is Aμ=(ϕ/c,A⃗ )=(ϕ(t,x⃗ ),A⃗ (t,x⃗ ))T.

Comment: To write exactly, Aμ=(ϕ/c,Ax,Ay,Az)=(ϕ(t,x⃗ ),A⃗ (t,x⃗ ))T.

Comment: "there are exact correspond , but depend on each other."

Comment: Probably I need to ask that what does "depending on" exactly means in the other post . I infer that means Lorentz transform though .